# Failed to connect to web.whatsapp.com port 443: Timed out

Tags: networking, vpn, timeout

For a few days now, I haven't been able to connect from one of my PCs to the web.whatsapp.com

```
curl "https://web.whatsapp.com"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to web.whatsapp.com port 443: Timed out
```

With all the other PCs I can connect with success to web.whatsapp.com  from the same home wifi network

I restored the windows host file but without any success

If I use a vpn I don't have the timeout anymore

What can it be?

***I fix it with Reset TCP/IP Stack Windows with Netsh Commands***

Comment: What is your DNS server set to? Have you tried setting it to `8.8.4.4`?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes I have tried without success. (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4)